# How to hide header and footer.php

Tags: php

Hi guys i m building a website in php i created my first 3 page

-header

-index

-footer

in index.php i use:

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>


<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

My question is:

if i go to my url http://localhost:8888/project/index.php

every its'ok

but if i write http://localhost:8888/project/header.php or footer

How i can not display the content it s in this two pages?

Because if i m using a redirect i have a blank page in index.php because the index.php include header and footer

Thanks a lot

Comment: The suggested answer below is great, but a better solution would be to move your include folder somewhere not web accessible.

Comment: How to make this? please

Comment: if your web folder is `/var/www/project/html` make sure your include folder is in `/var/www/project/include`. Only `html` is web accessible. So your index.php will reference it like this `include '../include/header.php';` I hope this makes senst.

Comment: You do realise linking to localhost is silly, as we can not access your localhost, hence the name...

Comment: you say for example: folder name: BLUE, i have index, footer, header in blue folder, and now created into blue folder a new folder ex: red and put header and footer in red folder?

Comment: i know localhost it s impossible to link, infact it s a example.... :)

Answer (score 4):

Define a constant in your scripts before including header or footer:

index.php:

```
define('MY_CONSTANT', 1);
include 'header.php';
//
include 'footer.php';
```

Then, in header.php and footer.php check if constant is not defined:

```
if(!defined('MY_CONSTANT')) {
    // You can show a message
    die('Access not allowed!');
    // Or send user to index.php, first delete above line (die)
    header('Location:index.php');
    exit;  // This line is needed to stop script execution
}
// rest of header and footer code
```

Comment: Or better -  redirect somewhere nicer than a white page with text and no nav links or any good explanation ;)

Comment: Always keep index.html in each folder in terms of security. You can also redirect to index page there.

Comment: Or better yet, have a front controller (even a very basic one) and throw a "accessNotAllowed" exception which ends up on a 404 page (but I'm probs pushing it now :D)

Answer (score 0):

go to your footer and header scripts, and make then a variable, for example:

```
$header = "<!doctype html><html><head>#head Content</head>";
```

and replace every qoutes with \" (look at the div class in $footer)

```
$footer = "<footer><div class=\"class\">#footer Content</div></footer></html>";
```

then in the index.php make it echo the variables

```
<?php
require_once("header.php");
require_once("footer.php");

echo $header;
echo $body;
echo $footer;
?>
```

then you can add this code to make it look like the file doesn't exist

```
<?php
  header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
  readfile('www.link.to/error-page/404');
  exit();
?>
```

Note: it's all up to you how you make your website, but this is the method I use, and it works fine.

extra:
you can make your $body like this
let's say you have a folder call scripts, you create a file called pager.php
and you add the code

```
<?php
    $dir = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
    if(empty($dir)) {
        require_once("templates/mainpage.php");
    } elseif ($dir == "page2") {
        require_once("templates/page2.php");
    } else {
        require_once("templates/pages-doesnt-exist.php");
    }

?>
```

remember to make a folder called "templates" and add all your pages in there,
then you'll be able to access all page from http://example.com/index.php/{pagename}
you can also add this code to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page2$ /index.php/page2 [L] --page wise condition
```

so http://example.com/page2 will access http://example.com/index.php/page2

Answer (score -1):

Compare $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to make sure the requested page/file is neither header.php nor footer.php

Comment: If he has multiple includes, he will have to keep adding more and more conditions.

Comment: He will not. He can just compare REQUEST_URI with the current file name.